# O que são comentários WET?

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação, comentários

O que são comentários W.E.T., em Python? Por que eles são ruins?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 17):

Não é só para Python, isso funciona para qualquer código. O acrônimo significa **Write Everything Twice** que é oposição ao [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) (foi escolhido assim para fazer um trocadilho com o DRY). São os comentários óbvios, que dizem exatamente o que o código já está dizendo de forma clara e legível para qualquer programador.

Se você escreveu um código simples e óbvio não tem porque comentar o que ele faz. Se não conseguiu fazer isso, refaça o código. Comentários servem para dizer porque fez uma coisa não óbvia, porque tem algo ali que parece estranho, porque teve que mexer naquilo ou de onde veio a informação referência para fazer aquilo. Comentário não é para dizer o que o código faz.

```
total = qtde * valor #calcula o total
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/WetComment.py).

Ah vá? Se não tivesse o comentário eu nunca saberia!

Esses comentários só são aceitáveis quando está sendo didático em uma amostra para ensinar alguém como se faz, não para código em produção.

Quase todo comentário viola o DRY do código e te obriga a ficar atento a ele em qualquer mudança no código.

O WET não se aplica só a comentários, qualquer duplicação real, e que não são iguais apenas por coincidência, devem ser evitadas.

Comment: Só para completar a ótima resposta: um dos piores problemas com comentários é que muitas vezes as pessoas não atualizam eles quando mudam o código. Então os comentários passam a ficar desatualizados e mentir para o programador, aumentando o tempo para entender o código.

Comment: Comentários que explicam a função e seus argumentos (e.g. JavaDocs) podem ser considerados WET também, caso seja algo muito óbvio? Ou é diferente, porque isso é uma documentação do código? Não sei se deveria fazer essa pergunta em uma pergunta nova.

Comment: É diferente. Mas tem problema semelhante, porque se você mudar o código e não mudar a doc tá lascado. Porém como costuma fazer parte do contrato, não deve mudar muito, o ideal é nunca, e se mudar deve ter um cuidado extra.