# Qual a melhor maneira de se declarar valores muito utilizados?

Tags: java, classes, desempenho, otimização, matemática

Tenho muitos valores monetários (impostos) que serão utilizados/somados a diversos serviços diferentes para totalizar um valor. Eu imaginei duas formas de fazer, porem não sei dizer se essas formas são boas, levando em consideração as boas praticas de código limpo e de fácil manutenção.

- Dependendo do serviço, ele pode utilizar 0 ou mais impostos em seus cálculos.
- Os impostos são atualizados de ano em ano.
- A descrição ao que o imposto faz referência e necessária.
- Posteriormente será criado um método para atualizar os valores de todos os impostos referente ao ano de atuação.

```
Forma 1:

    public class Impostos {    

    //Esse imposto e referente a tal coisa
    public static BigDecimal imposto1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(24.60);

    //Esse imposto e referente a tal coisa
    public static BigDecimal imposto2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0); 
}

Forma 2 :

     public enum Impostos {
     
      IMPOSTO_1("Esse imposto e referente a tal coisa", BigDecimal.valueOf(24.50)),
      IMPOSTO_2("Esse imposto e referente a tal coisa", BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0));

    String descricao;
    BigDecimal valor;

    Imposto(String descricao, BigDecimal valor){
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

Qual das duas seria mais viável para diversas utilizações em diferentes serviços? Ou teria uma forma melhor de faze-la?

Comment: Se o valor dos impostos pode mudar, enum não é uma boa, pois a ideia de um enum é ter valores fixos. Talvez um `List` ou `Map` sejam melhores nesse caso

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, quero dizer que parece que gosta de conceitos que não conhece bem e isso pode atrapalhar. Em computação, ou outras coisas na vida, não use o que não domina porque fará criar algo problemático. Grande parte das pessoas gostam de estar no moda, então querem usar boas práticas, código limpo, fazer padrões de projeto, etc. Porém sem dominar completamente essas coisas a aplicação será errada e criará mais problema que solução. Fazer algo de fácil manutenção de forma coerente é muito mais importante que aplicar conceitos de forma errada. É extremamente comum as pessoas, até que podem ser chamadas de "experientes", terem aprendido errado, fazem errado e ensinam errado, até por não levar em conta o contexto, elas só querem parecer que fazem certo, que estão na moda.

Reforço o comentário do hkotsubo. Veja mais sobre em [Uma enumeração deve ser constante no tempo de vida da solução?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101).

Nenhuma das opções parecem boas porque considera constante algo que é variável.

Não é que não possa fazer assim, mas elas não parecem adequadas para o problema. Aí volto ao primeiro parágrafo. Para ser o ideal precisa saber bem qual é o problema hoje e como ele pode evoluir depois. Um dos erros que programadores mais cometem hoje em dia é não trabalhar com requisitos bastante fundamentados e detalhados.

> Sem saber onde quer chegar qualquer caminho serve porque eles te levarão ao local errado.

Em sistemas reais, tratamento de imposto é muito mais complexo do que isso, é dos problemas mais difíceis de resolver em sistemas administrativos, é das condições que mais mudam, especialmente no Brasil, e portanto precisa estar capacitado a lidar com todas as situações, exceções e mudanças que possam vir a ter. Essa forma parece bem ingênua.

A primeira forma é quase um `enum`, na prática funciona como uma enumeração constante, então cai no mesmo problema. E ela nem deveria ser considerada porque ela faz menos que a segunda, portanto elas não são comparáveis, e a segunda só estaria mais errada se ela faz o que não deve fazer, e aí a primeira seria melhor, mas não parece. Quando for completando o código, se for algo real, verá que ambas não atendem bem ao problema.

Provavelmente teria que criar uma classe para cada imposto [com padrões de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187908/101) que ajudam aplicar o que é necessário nas diversas situações.

Eu já vi e mexi com diversos ERPs em 40 anos e nunca gostei de nenhuma solução, nem mesmo eu achei uma ideal e cada situação eu vejo uma forma melhor de fazer, em geral não seguindo "boa práticas", porque elas me induziriam a coisas ruins, e não fazendo código tão limpo em algo tão complexo. Em alguns casos deixar as coisas para o banco de dados ou fazer tudo de forma dinâmica pode ser mais fácil de dar manutenção, apesar de eu não gostar tanto da solução.

Pense como vai resolver impostos que se resolvem em matriz, que são progressivos, que possuem exceções, que interagem de forma inconsistente e tem regras bem esquisitas.

Mas se for para resolver ingenuamente faça o mais simples que dá o resultado esperado, sempre.

Eu só não me preocuparia muito com desempenho em algo assim, até que se torne um problema. E olha que eu sou fanático por desempenho. Só de usar `BigDecimal` já é algo ruim para desempenho, mas Java não tem solução melhor, e isso parece que você sabe, pode ser um caso que está seguindo uma boa prática para o bem. Ou quem sabe entenda porque é o correto fazer assim, o que deixa de ser boa prática e passa ser a solução correta, que é muito melhor.

Faça de um jeito ou de outro e sinta na pele os problemas dando manutenção durante anos, e aprenda o que funciona melhor, quem sabe em menos de 40 anos tenha mais claro do que eu tenho hoje de como resolver algo que faz malabarismos assim.

Se treinar o erro é ele que fará para o resto da vida. Por isso precisa estar sempre aberto a mudar o que já fez antes. E para isso não pode por fé em boas práticas, código limpo e coisas afins, elas não são regras estáticas e universais a serem seguidas, e não resolvem problemas reais. Exemplos artificiais treinam o erro, se a pessoa não souber isolar isso, elas tornam aquilo uma boa prática.

Me parece que a primeira é um começo melhor que a segunda por deixar um pouco mais flexível, ainda que insuficiente para o uso real.

`enum` do Java é mais poderoso que da maioria das linguagens, o que o torna até algo que não é bem um `enum`, mas não o suficiente para ser usado para além de uma enumeração constante, o que é melhor assim.

Veja sobre comentários:

- [Por que não comentar o código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399158/101)
- [Como saber a medida certa de comentários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15488/101)
- [O que são comentários WET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363051/101)

Modelar projetos é a parte mais difícil do desenvolvimento de software, porque é mais humano que exato.